# Provide credentials for Oracle database when opening MXD file?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, oracle-dbms

I need  to open a MXD file from a Python toolbox (so that I can automatically export it to a PDF). The file contains a connection to an Oracle 11g database, and I need to somehow provide the credentials to the database. None of the methods I have tried so far have worked - the PDF always comes out without any of the data from the database. How can I tell ArcGIS what username and password to use?

**Attempt 1:** Reference a SDE file:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "credentials.sde"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_file)
arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, pdf_file)
```

**Attempt 2:** Create a SDE file:

```
arcpy.CreateArcSDEConnectionFile_management (
   out_folder_path = "C:\\Path",
   out_name = "temp.sde",
   server = "prod.world",
   service = "prod.world",
   account_authentication = "DATABASE_AUTH",
   username = "username",
   password = "password",
   save_username_password = "SAVE_USERNAME"
)
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_file)
arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, pdf_file)
```

I am unsure of what I should use for the parameters `server` and `service`? When I look at the connection properties of an SDE file created from ArcCatalog it doesn't have those options. Instead it has the single option "Instance" with the value "sde:oracle11g:prod.world", and "Oracle" selected in the "Database platform" dropdown instead of "Application Server".

**Attempt 3:** Somehow make the MXD remember the username and password. Unsure of how to do that, though.

Comment: The SDE connection file needs to be set as the data source for the layer in the mxd. I would just loop through the layers one by one set the datasources like `lyr.findAndReplaceWorkspacePath(find_workspace_path=lyr.dataSource, replace_workspace_path=r"C:\Newpath\To\SDE_ConnectionFile.sde")` More info here: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Updating_and_fixing_data_sources_with_arcpy_mapping/00s30000004p000000/

Comment: Try setting `service = "sde:oracle11g:prod.world"` and `server = " "` (a single space, since it's a required value but not needed). That worked for my connection to an Oracle database with SDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a **direct connection**, create a connection file to your database in `Catalog window > Database Connections > Add DataBase Connection`. In this case your **Instance** would be something like `sde:oracle11g:servername`

If you use an **ArcSDE Service connection** (not direct connection), create a connection with `Create ArcSDE Connection File` geoprocessing tool. 
In this case the **Service** parameter would be the ArcSDE Service name or port (e.g. 5151).

Either way check `Save username and password`.

Open your MXD with ArcMap. Remove any layer that is from your enterprise (oracle) database and re-add them from the connection file you have created in the previous step.

Comment: Thansk for the reply! This helped me on the right track. To get it to work, I had to do some modifications though - see my answer for details.

Answer (score 3):

In the end I managed to solve this by using a combination of Farid Chers answer and Eok Ns comment.

First, I created a SDE file with the following code:

```
arcpy.CreateArcSDEConnectionFile_management (
   out_folder_path = "C:\\Path",
   out_name = "temp.sde",
   server = " ", #Note the single space!
   service = "sde:oracle11g:prod.world",
   account_authentication = "DATABASE_AUTH",
   username = "username",
   password = "password",
   save_username_password = "SAVE_USERNAME"
)
```

For some reason just creating it from ArcCatalog will not work, as only the username and not the password is saved.

Then I modified my MXD to use this connection. I did not have to remove the layer and add it again (as Farid suggested). It was enough to just go to "Properties" -> "Source" -> "Change query", and there change to the SDE i just created in the "Connection" drop down menu.